# multiplication error

Tags: java, android

If I multiply 12 x 25.4 i get 304.7 whereas I expect 304.8.  I see that using odd numbers x 25.4 I get the correct answers but using even numbers always seem to be off by 0.1.  I am writing a scientific app that is heavily based on formulas so any insight would be helpful.

```
if (((m1_sqs1_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString().equals("in"))))  

    { // start square in inches
         double m1_sqs1_eng = new Double(m1_sqs1.getText().toString()); 

         double square_effective_dia_inch = m1_sqs1_eng;

         double square_effective_dia_mm = square_effective_dia_inch * 25.4;
         m1_ed_mm.setText(Double.toString(square_effective_dia_mm));

    } // end square in inches
```

Comment: Welcome to the world of floating point math. You don't say what you're defining the types as, but if you're doing scientific work I'd look around at existing libraries like jscience. (Didn't notice the android part, don't know if it works on android.)

Comment: Some code would help, but you should also probably familiarize yourself with [what every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: Wow, 8 answered questions and none accepted. Impressive!

Comment: D'oh!  I didn't see that when I added my answer.

Comment: If I multiply 12 by 25.4 using double precision, I get 304.799999999999954525264911353588104248046875.  How are you displaying it?

Comment: i added some of my code to show what i am doing.

Comment: If Hovercrafts comment was to me then i will go back through my posts and answer my questions  I thought when someone else provided an answer that we were all good

Comment: @WmBurkert: To accept answers for your previous questions you need to go back to your questions and select the best one by clicking on the check mark next to the one answer that was best.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Floating point number types in Java are approximations.  Try adding 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 as `float` type and you might end up with 10.00000003.

To ensure accurate math, try using the `java.math.BigDecimal` type.  It is a memory hog, but is accurate.

Comment: that is a poor example.  Each of those integers have exact representations as `float` values, and so does their sum.  Your general point is correct though.

Comment: @StephenC I confess my knowledge is limited on the underlying issue, but I recently tried to use a float as a counter, incrementing by whole numbers each time in a loop.  The end result was a decimal like above.  Is that a difference scenario?

Comment: The difference is that the case where you had this problem probably strayed into the range of `int` values that have no exact `float` equivalent.  A `float` has only 23 bits of precision in the significand, so (for example) odd numbers greater than 2^23 cannot be represented exactly.  (2^23 is roughly 8 million.)  By contrast, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4` and `10` all can be represented exactly.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what programming language you're using, but 12 * 25.4 gives me 304.8 when I do this using Java:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   double result = 12 * 25.4;

   System.out.printf("Result: %.1f%n", result );
}
```

But seriously -- how are you displaying the result obtained? Are you using one of the many numeric formatting options available in Java (one of which is displayed above)? Also do you understand the limits to precision when using 64-bit IEEE 754 floating point (double) variables? They are pretty accurate and useful for most floating-point applications, but not applications that have strict precision requirements such as financial calculations.