# Value not adding/subtracting correct amount and if/else statement bugs

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, if-statement

I have a script that adds elements to a div, rotates them for a set amount of time, then when the amount of time has been met, the rotation stops and a random element within the div is animated.

I have a few issues:

1. if you turn the `// alert(maxspeed)` and `//alert(maxcount)` alerts on and click on 'Run' (Edit: Click append all first) to run the script, you will see that values start by adding/subtracting at rates of `0.1` but will lose out on 0.00000001 or so here or there, why is this(Memory issue due to poor coding maybe?)?
2. after clicking on 'Run' (Edit: Click append all first), the images will begin to animate, but why is the animation random at times? When all it should be doing is increasing the `maxspeed` by a value of `0.1` a time
3. Finally; why does it seemingly hit the 'else' stage of my if/else statement before the conditions of 'if' have been met?

I'm a newcomer to JS/jQuery so please excuse any poor coding (I followed a tutorial to achieve the rotation effect).

Here is my jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/pAk9N/9/ and jQuery code below, thanks :)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//You can edit the following file paths to change images in selection
var img1 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var img2 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var img3 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var img4 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var img5 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var img6 = '<img src="/img/logo.png">';
var all = img1 + img2 + img3 + img4 + img5 + img6;

//Rotation part 1
var maxspeed = 0.00;
var minspeed = 0.01;
var stopped = 0.0;        
var speed = maxspeed;        
var radius = 100;        
var count = 0;

function rotate()
{
    var centerx = $(document).width()/2;
    var centery = $(document).height()/2;            
    var num_items = $("#container > img").length;        
    $("#container > img").each(function(){
        var angle = count * (Math.PI/180);                
        var newx = centerx + Math.cos(angle)*radius - $(this).width()/2;                
        var newy = centery + Math.sin(angle)*radius - $(this).height()/2;                
        $(this).css("left",newx+"px").css("top",newy+"px");                
        count += 360/num_items + speed;
    });
}

//Rotation part 2
setInterval(rotate,1000/360);
$(document).mousemove(function(e)
{
    var dw = $(document).width();
    var dh = $(document).height();
    var itemh = $("#container > img").height();
    var itemw = $("#container > img").width();

    if (e.pageX > dw/2-radius-itemw/2 && e.pageX < dw/2 + radius + itemw/2 && e.pageY > dh/2-radius-itemh/2 && e.pageY < dh/2+radius+itemh/2)
        {
            speed = minspeed;
        }
    else
        {
            speed = maxspeed;
        }
});

//Append elements to container
$("#appendall").click(function(){$('#container').append(all);});
$('#append').children().eq(2).click(function(){$('#container').append(img1);});
$('#append').children().eq(3).click(function(){$('#container').append(img2);});
$('#append').children().eq(4).click(function(){$('#container').append(img3);});
$('#append').children().eq(5).click(function(){$('#container').append(img4);});
$('#append').children().eq(6).click(function(){$('#container').append(img5);});
$('#append').children().eq(7).click(function(){$('#container').append(img6);});

//Refresh page
$("#reset").click(function(){location.reload();});

//IF speed is greater than 0 - ELSE add animation to div element
$("#run").click(function(){
    var maxcount = 1.00;
    var incdec = 0.01;
    counter()
    function counter()
    {
        if (parseFloat(maxcount) >= 0.00)
            {
                maxcount = parseFloat(maxcount) - parseFloat(incdec);
                maxspeed = parseFloat(maxspeed) + parseFloat(incdec);
               // alert(maxspeed)
                //alert(maxcount)
                setTimeout(counter,40);
            }         
        else
            {     
                maxspeed = 0;
                //Find amount of div elements and add 1
                var brewees = $('#container').children().length +=1;
                //get a random number
                var rand = (Math.floor(Math.random()*brewees));    
                var ap = '20px';
                var ab = '#ddd';
                var ad = 1000;
                //match random number corrosponding child in div
                $('#container').children().eq(parseFloat(rand))
                .animate({padding: ap, background : ab}, {duration:ad});        
            }
    }
});
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to your first question is that floating point arithmetic is an approximation; you shouldn't expect to get exact answers.  There are many questions on SO about this; here is a recent one: [multiplication error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7749162/multiplication-error)

As for your other questions, they may be related to the floating point arithmetic issue above, the result of poor coding, or something else.  I'm having trouble reading your code and/or understanding what you want, even from the JSFiddle.  Here are some things to do:

- Try defining your functions (counter, rotate) at the highest level, not inside the onclick handler.
- It seems like you run `rotate()` from the very beginning, instead of when `run` is clicked.  Seems a bit early, no?
- parseFloat() is only necessary when you're trying to convert a String (e.g. "1.94") into a float (e.g. 1.94).  You don't seem to be using Strings, here, so it's probably not necessary.
- Drop the extras.  All that "Add Luke" stuff is not essential to solving this problem.

Once you boil your code down to the bare minimum, you might solve your problem and/or we can help further.

Another option is to use the jQuery Animation features.  There are a few rotation plugins I see after some quick searching.  You can also just use the core `animate()` to modify the CSS.

Comment: Great, I'll have a look in to some of this and come back later. Thanks!

Comment: Made a lot of changes and got it running a lot smoother now. Thanks for your help! http://jsfiddle.net/zAPsY/7/

Answer (score 0):

Floating point is an approximation, so....
let's say you want to keep subtracting 0.01 repeatedly.
let

```
var dec = 0.01; //decrement
var num = 5;
```

if you keep doing

```
num -= dec;
```

you will get inaccurate results. 
To normalize this, try:

```
num = Math.floor((num - dec)*100)/100;
```

**Note: ** The same thing can be done with increments (just replace '-' with '+')